# How can I write a for loop for list?

Tags: c++, list, function, for-loop

I am currently trying to write a loop for list . my code is :

```
template<typename T>
void Bubblesorting(list<T> & mylist)
{ 
    typename T::const_iterator it1;
    typename T::const_iterator it2;
    for(it1=mylist.begin();it1!=mylist.end();it1++)
        for(it2=mylist.begin();it2!=mylist.end()-(it1-begin());it2++)
            if((*(std::next(it2,1))<*it2)
                swap((*(std::next(it2,1)),*it2);
        cout << *it2 << ' ';
}
```

Compilation fails with:

```
 error C2958: the left parenthesis '(' was not matched correctly
```

Can you please help me detect where exactly is the problem?how can I write a for loop for elements of list?

Comment: List iterator is not a random access so `+` operator won't work, and you are passing a reference to the `const` container while trying to mutate it inside the method.

Answer (score 6):

Function bodies have `{}` around them. In fact, you'll also need that around the body of your outer loop.

Your iterator type is also wrong, since `T` is the list type, not the list's element type. Further, it will need to be a `const_iterator`, since you pass the list in by `const` reference.

```
typename T::const_iterator it1;
```

Finally, neither `(it2)+1` nor `mylist.end()-it1` are possible since lists do not accommodate *random access*. You can fake it with `std::advance` and friends, but since traversing a list is non-trivial (due to the design of the data structure), this is made difficult for a reason.

In general I would revisit the concept of this entire function. Why not use `std::list::sort`?

I recommend picking from [these books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I'm ashamed to say I missed that >.>

Comment: I think `{}` missing was unintentional

Comment: *"lists do not accommodate random access."* Then why recommend `std::sort` for it? :)

Comment: @P0W: If any of these build-breaking errors were _intentional_ then the OP is SOL AFAIAC.

Comment: @jrok: I don't know what you're talking about! *whistles*

Comment: Thanks @LightnessRacesinOrbit ya I miss {}. I tried to correct them, is it posssible to see my code again , actually I want to Implement a bubblesort function.

Comment: @user3140486: Just imagine that the first sentence of my answer isn't there, and that _all the others_ still are.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the missing `{}` you need to define your iterator as `typename T::const_iterator it1;`.

Comment: Of all of the problems with this function, this is the least problematic.

Comment: The question states that compilation fails and this is why it does not compile.

Comment: This is indeed the cause of two of the four reported errors.

Comment: There are other reasons why it won't compile- much more serious ones.

Comment: While I agree, I do not think it warranted a downvote. I also do not believe there is a level of severity in compilation error. Anyway the question has been edited and all the original errors have disappeared so it is unfortunately not relevant anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, your real code contains all the missing `{}`, otherwise there would be far more errors.

`T` appears to be the container type, not the value type, so the iterator type would be `typename T::iterator`; except that the container is `const`, so you can only get a `const_iterator` out of it. But your code tries to modify the container, which isn't possible if it's `const`. Perhaps you want to copy the argument into a new container, and sort and return that; or perhaps you want to take a non-const reference and sort the container in place (not returning anything).

You're trying to perform *random-access* operations on an iterator type that doesn't support them. List iterators are *bidirectional* - you can increment them and decrement them, but you can't add arbitrary amounts to them, or subtract them to give a distance.

Perhaps it would be more appropriate to use a random-access container like `vector`. Or perhaps you could replace `it+n` with `std::next(it,n)` and `it2-it1` with `std::distance(it1,it2)`. (Or, if you're stuck with a pre-C++11 library, write your own versions of these functions.)

Finally, `it2!=mylist.end()-it1` doesn't make sense; the left-hand side is a distance, which can't be compared to an iterator. Perhaps you want `end() - (it1-begin())`, referring to the position as far from the end as `it1` is from the beginning. More likely, you want to iterate from `it1` to `end()-1`.

Comment: thanks for clear guidance,I've just started programming, my purpose is to implement a bubblesort function for list<T>                                                           for i = 0, … , n − 2
   for j = 0, … , n − i − 2
     if aj+1 < aj
        swap aj and aj+1